# PRISM. Task with RegisterInstance

Tags: .net, silverlight-4.0, c#-4.0, unity-container, prism

I would like to understand something.

I have "Service" silverlight application project that contains Module class and next code line into its "Initialize" method in order to register type:

```
unityContainer.RegisterInstance<IService>(instance);
```

And I have another "Controls" silverlight application project. Module is described into "catalog.xaml" file:

```
<Modularity:ModuleInfo
    Ref="Service.xap"
    ModuleName="ServiceModule"
    ModuleType="Service.ModuleDefinitions.Module, Service, Version=1.0.0.0">
</Modularity:ModuleInfo>
```

You can find "Bootstrapper" code below:

```
protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
{
    Uri uri = new Uri("catalog.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
    ModuleCatalog moduleCatalog = Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModuleCatalog.CreateFromXaml(uri);
    // NOTE: State of "ServiceModule" is "NotStarted" here...
    return moduleCatalog;
}

protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
{
    Shell shell = new Shell();
    Application.Current.RootVisual = shell;
    IRegionManager regionManager = Container.Resolve<IRegionManager>();
    regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MainRegion", typeof(MainView));
    return shell;
}
```

One ViewModel class (into "Controls" project) contains reference to IService interface that has to be registered into Modul class of "Service" project.

CreateModuleCatalog() and CreateShell() methods were executed without any problem during programm debug, but I got exception before executing of Initialize() method with registration of IService.

Error message: "The current type, Service.ServiceReference.IService, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?"

I thought that I need register/mapping types only one time and if I have done it into Module class of Service project then I didn't have to do it Controls project again.

I need help to understand situation above  :)

Comment: Are you having trouble with this code: unityContainer.RegisterInstance<IService>(instance);?
Or when trying to get the object back from the container?

Comment: I had problem at second point. "unityContainer.RegisterInstance<IService>(instance)" code was not run - this code was into Initialize method of my ServiceModule. But that error was not reproduced if Registration code has been into CreateShell method of Bootstrapper class. I thought that CreateModuleCatalog method would initialize my ServiceModule and run Register code. But module initializing code is executed after CreateModuleCatalog and CreateShell methods of my Bootstrapper.

Comment: I understand that my explanations are not very clear :)  But I am trying to understand situation without deep knowledge of behavior and structure of prism unity practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure this code is executing before trying to resolve the object from the container?

```
unityContainer.RegisterInstance<IService>(instance);
```

As explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648449.aspx), using the RegisterInstance method with an interface automatically establishes a mapping, so there is no need for you to do it explicitly.

However, if you are trying to resolve an interface without the [type mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650319.aspx) being established first you will get the error you are getting, as there is no way to instantiate an interface.

Comment: Thank you. I am investigating prism unity/prism mef/mef 2 now in order to find best solution for me. It is my first silverlight project and I would like to do it as good as possible. I don't have common template for similar projects. As I see now It will be MVC2  site with Silverlight controls (MVVM and MEF). I selected silverlight-enabled WCF service for controls but I don't know their advantages (by example if I use WCF RIA service).